# how to make carousel slide and validation work normally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

any can help me ??? i am trying to run carousel slide and validation in bootstrap 3. after i insert scripts for the validation, the carousel doesn't work

i have tried to apply noConlict() many times but it still doesn't work. 
here the scripts i have

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq=$.noConflict();
jq('document').ready(function(){
jq('form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        country: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
    window.location.href('seminar.php?module=success');
});
    jq('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval:3000
    });
    jq('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle');
    });


</script>
```

Comment: which files do you have on your site and which are you using ?

Comment: i have edited the script.... i hope you can see all the scripts...

Comment: @Izekid i am trying to use carousel and validation form in one page but it seems that they cannot work together...the carousel cannot slide the images when i tried to use the validation script

Comment: Do you get the error server side or client side?

Comment: there is no error statement....it's only the slide doesn't run as usual